# Cross-compiling Open NI for Linux MIPS Platform

Tags: mips, kinect, openni, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile Open NI in a MIPS based platform. But I see that all the header files check for platform and reject MIPS as unsupported platform.

Snippet:

```
#elif defined(ANDROID) && defined(__arm__)
        #include "Android-Arm/XnPlatformAndroid-Arm.h"
#elif (linux && (i386 || __x86_64__))
        #include "Linux-x86/XnPlatformLinux-x86.h"
#elif (linux && __arm__)
        #include "Linux-Arm/XnPlatformLinux-Arm.h"
#elif _ARC
        #include "ARC/XnPlatformARC.h"
#elif (__APPLE__)
        #include "MacOSX/XnPlatformMacOSX.h"
#else
        #error OpenNI Platform Abstraction Layer - Unsupported Platform!
#endif
```

As far as I have checked the code does not have any assembly code that might be processor-specific.

Is it safe to ignore the compiler error and proceed (by commenting out the #error statements) with the cross-compilation or is there a good reason why MIPS is not supported by Open NI?